# iPad 3 retina display testing? Without an iPad 3

Tags: ipad, retina-display

I am from India, we dont have the iPad 3 launched here yet. I want my apps to support the higher resolution but have no way to test on the 3rd generation iPad.

Any advise how can I ensure that my apps support iPad3 retina display?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you download the latest version of Xcode from the Mac app store, the simulator now includes the ability to simulate an iPad Retina display - on the simulator menu "Hardware", "Device", "iPad (Retina)".

Note, because the display is so large, you may want to scale down the display of the simulator - on the menu, "Window", "Scale", "25%".

This will enable you to ensure that if you are loading @2X images, they are loading correctly.  It will not help you ensure that your animations are smooth - you'll need a real device for that.  I tested my app using the simulator and everything seemed fine, but when I got my device realized I had some problems related to the increased resolution.

If you've coded your app in a resolution independent way and have a Retina iPhone, it wouldn't hurt to try running it there as well - it's a very different context, but has some things in common.

Ultimately though, you will only know that your app is properly supporting the iPad Retina display by testing it on a 3rd gen iPad.

Comment: Great! I will do this. I do have every other device apart from the new iPad.